# Error in building vue application with npm run dev

Tags: npm, vue.js

Find the below steps i have tried to build the vue application.

```
E:\vue\my-app>npm run dev

> monitoring@1.0.0 dev E:\vue\my-app
> node build/dev-server.js

> Starting dev server...


ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                 3:48:36 PM

This relative module was not found:

* ./src/main.js in multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
> Listening at http://localhost:8080
```

I am using

```
Node - 6.11.0
npm - 3.10.10
vue - 2.8.2
```

Comment: i don't think that anybody can tell what is wrong - at least not from this piece of output. Best guess : It's what it says. There is no main.js in the given part

Comment: Please provide some more details about error if you have!!

Comment: @FrankProvost - There is some installation issue, because of this i am not able to launch the application. Now i fixed by doing a fresh install.

Comment: Can you post your package.json script section and the webpack.config?

Comment: @aprouja1 - It is fixed now.

Comment: Missing some dependencies and that vue version isnt valid